# Iterate over all objects of the model in Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

How can I itarate over all objects of the model and how 3D-objects are stored and programmatically represented in Forge Viewer?

Answer (score 1):

To iterate the scene hierarchy of a model in Forge Viewer, you can use the "instance tree", for example:

```js
const instanceTree = viewer.model.getInstanceTree();
const rootNodeId = instanceTree.getRootId();
const traverseRecursively = true;
function callback(dbid) {
    console.log('Found object ID', dbid);
}
instanceTree.enumNodeChildren(rootNodeId, callback, traverseRecursively);
```

For more info, check out this blog post: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/working-2d-and-3d-scenes-and-geometry-forge-viewer.

Comment: My viewer.model is undefined, does this mean I missed something in my revit project?

Comment: The `viewer.model` property is only available *after* you actually load a model. So make sure that you are not calling the code accessing `viewer.model` "too early".

Comment: I fixed previous issue, but now my instanceTree is undefined

Comment: The instance tree is downloaded in a separate file as well, so you'll want to wait until it's available, for example, by adding an event listener for the [Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/#object-tree-created-event).

Comment: Glad I could help :)